# HTML and JavaScript: different values depending on the radio button

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, var, radio-group

I have a pretty simple problem, but I can't find the answer online, so now I'll ask here. I hope someone can help. 
I have 2 questions, and beneath each of those, I have a group of radio buttons, each with 3 buttons: 'Enig', 'Neutral' or 'Uenig'. I want to assign each option a value of 1, 0, or -1, and depending on what is chosen, give the question or group that value. 
This applies to both of the 2 groups of radio buttons. 
At last, I want to display the total score of the 2 questions (q1+q2), when a button is pressed. 
I really hope someone knows how to do this, it would really be a great help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my opinion, you should write all the HTML that you need, after that with Javascript, you can hide or show whatever group or text you want.
In the final page, you just show the score with Javascript.

```
var totalpoints = 0;
function showOptions() {
    if (document.getElementById('#radio1').checked) {
        //show the group that you want
        document.getElementById('#gruop1').style.display = 'block';
        totalpoints += 1;
    }
    else {
        //do something
    }
}

    document.getElementById("#totalscore").innerHTML = "Final score: " + totalpoints;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
 $("#get").click(function(){
   var q1 = $("input[name=group1]:checked").val();
    var integer = parseInt(q1, 10);

   var q2 = $("input[name=group2]:checked").val();
    var integer2 = parseInt(q2, 10);

   var sum = integer  + integer2;
      alert(sum)
$("#result").html("You have selected " +sum);
  });
});
```

```css
label {
  display : block;
  margin-bottom : 5px;
}
#result {
  margin-top : 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>
 group 1
</h1>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="group1" value="1"> 1
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="group1" value="2"> 2
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="group1" value="3"> 3
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="group1" value="4"> 4
</label>

<br>

<h1>
group2
</h1>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="group2" value="1"> 1
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="group2" value="2"> 2
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="group2" value="3"> 3
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="group2" value="4"> 4
</label>

<button id="get">
  Get the checked value
</button>
<div id="result">
    
</div>
```